# Unable to update row in MySQL using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
public class UpdateEmployee extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
        EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails();
        SessionFactory fact=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session ses = fact.openSession();
        int emp_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("emp_id"));
        int new_emp_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("new_emp_id"));
        String emp_name = request.getParameter("name");
        String emp_designation_id = request.getParameter("designationid");
        String emp_skills = request.getParameter("skills");
        String emp_department_id = request.getParameter("departmentid");
        String emp_notes = request.getParameter("notes");
        String emp_email = request.getParameter("email");
        String emp_phone = request.getParameter("phone");
        String emp_username = request.getParameter("username");
        String emp_password = request.getParameter("password");
        emp.setEmp_department_id(emp_department_id);
        emp.setEmp_designation_id(emp_designation_id);
        emp.setEmp_email(emp_email);
        emp.setEmp_id(new_emp_id);
        emp.setEmp_join_date(null);
        emp.setEmp_name(emp_name);
        emp.setEmp_notes(emp_notes);
        emp.setEmp_password(emp_password);
        emp.setEmp_phone(emp_phone);
        emp.setEmp_skills(emp_skills);
        emp.setEmp_username(emp_username);
        Query query = ses.createQuery("update EmployeeDetails emp set emp_id=:new_emp_id,emp_name=:emp_name,emp_designation_id=:emp_designation_id,emp_skills=:emp_skills,emp_department_id=:emp_department_id,emp_notes=:emp_notes,emp_email=:emp_email,emp_phone=:emp_phone,emp_username=:emp_username,emp_password=:emp_password where emp_id=:emp_id");
        query.setParameter(emp_id, emp_id);
        query.setParameter(new_emp_id, new_emp_id);
        query.setParameter(emp_name, emp_name);
        query.setParameter(emp_designation_id, emp_designation_id);
        query.setParameter(emp_skills, emp_skills);
        query.setParameter(emp_department_id, emp_department_id);
        query.setParameter(emp_notes, emp_notes);
        query.setParameter(emp_email, emp_email);
        query.setParameter(emp_username, emp_username);
        query.setParameter(emp_password, emp_password);
        int result = query.executeUpdate();
        out.print(result);
    }

}
```

My result when i try to update:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!
    org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:55)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:61)
    org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:382)
    org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:362)
    com.unisys.servlets.UpdateEmployee.doPost(UpdateEmployee.java:59)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I'm new to hibernate. I've looked up lot of references, any sort of guidance regarding updation would be much appreciated. 
I'm trying to update one value in the row using emp_id value and updating all the other columns in the database.

Comment: It might be caused by the parameters not being set in the order they appear within your query. You can add a parameter to the setParameter to specify the position. Like so: setParameter(1, new_emp_id, new_emp_id); Remember that the position starts at 1 not 0.

Comment: Remove colon in between this statement in update statement....emp_id=:new_emp_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. But here the guy is mixed up the "Named" parameters with indexed parameter concepts.

```
query.setParameter("emp_id", emp_id);
    query.setParameter("new_emp_id", new_emp_id);
    query.setParameter("emp_name", emp_name);
    query.setParameter("emp_designation_id", emp_designation_id);
    query.setParameter("emp_skills", emp_skills);
    query.setParameter("emp_department_id", emp_department_id);
    query.setParameter("emp_notes", emp_notes);
    query.setParameter("emp_email", emp_email);
    query.setParameter("emp_username", emp_username);
    query.setParameter("emp_password", emp_password);
    query.setParameter("emp_phone", emp_phone);
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

The main purpose of named parameter is we don't worry about the order and it is easily  understandable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!` is misleading.

In your JPQL query, you use this condition  `emp_phone=:emp_phone` with the `emp_phone` parameter but the parameter value is never set in the query :

```
    Query query = ses.createQuery(
     "update EmployeeDetails emp set..emp_phone=:emp_phone");

    query.setParameter(emp_id, emp_id);
    query.setParameter(new_emp_id, new_emp_id);
    query.setParameter(emp_name, emp_name);
    query.setParameter(emp_designation_id, emp_designation_id);
    query.setParameter(emp_skills, emp_skills);
    query.setParameter(emp_department_id, emp_department_id);
    query.setParameter(emp_notes, emp_notes);
    query.setParameter(emp_email, emp_email);
    query.setParameter(emp_username, emp_username);
    query.setParameter(emp_password, emp_password);
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

So, Hibernate throws an exception.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But here the guy is mixed up the "Named" parameters with indexed parameter concepts.